# Preventing login attacks on my spring web app

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have a live spring web app running on amazon and I have recently found login attacks from various IPs. So far nothing has been compromised as the login system is secure enough, with complex passowrds, and encoding with salt etc..
However, I would like to prevent this.

One thing that the logs revealed was that the attackers are somehow able to reach my service classes (only the authenticaltion manager) circumventing my login page. I dont have a special url for login, but how is it possible to call the authentication manager/service etc without going via the login jsp ? I can see logging from loadUserByUsername() method of my authentication service class (which implements UserDetailsService).
Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need login.jsp, you can simulate a person posting the login form just by performing HTTP post with all the parameters right?

If all the request coming from the same IP, you can configure your firewall to block it. Other mechanism is to put a delay after a number of failures (eg 30min delay after 5 subsequent failures).

If you want to go further, two form authentication will increase security, eg perform sms confirmation if user is logging in from unknown IP / computer

Comment: Thanks, I found the answer to how they are login. By doing http post as you said , something  like  `curl --data "j_username=xxx&j_password=yyy" http://www.mysecureurl.com/j_spring_security_check` . Will be asking a followup question in a new thread.